# Returning Only Distinct Mongo Object IDs in Mongo View

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongo/mongoose to return a filtered list of values based on distinct mongo object "_id" values in my Mongo view. Right now the same client will return several times. What I want, when I don't pass a specific category, is a list of all clients, but for each one to show up just once per unique mongo object `_id`. This is what my code looks like:

```
if (category === '') {
    db.collection('view_clients_datagrid').distinct("_id");
}
```

At present this doesn't seem to be having any effect. I don't get an error, but neither does the data filter as expected. Does this syntax look correct for returning distinct values from the generated mongo view titled `'view_clients_datagrid'`? Is this an operation you can run on a view?

Each document from my generated mongo view looks like this:

```
    {
        "_id": "3dz26954121g3813be096f8d",
        "initDate": "2010-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "agencyLink": "73h645365f0613be08092d",
        "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        },
        "birthDate": "1982-07-04T05:00:00.000Z"
    },
```